# UIBeziepath with Color gradient

Tags: ios, gradient, uibezierpath

I'm drawing a circle and exerthing is fine as long as the circle is only in one color. But I need to have two colors, where position 0 is Green and position 360 is red. position 180 should be half green half red.

Here the code that draws my circle

```
let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)

        // Calculate the center difference between the end and start angle
        let angleDiff: CGFloat = endAngle.toRads - startAngle.toRads
        // Calculate how much we should draw depending on the value set
        let arcLenPerValue = angleDiff / CGFloat(maxValue)
        // The inner end angle some basic math is done
        let innerEndAngle = arcLenPerValue * CGFloat(value) + startAngle.toRads

        // The radius for style 1 is set below
        // The radius for style 1 is a bit less than the outer, this way it looks like its inside the circle
        var radiusIn = (max(bounds.width - outerRingWidth*2 - innerRingSpacing, bounds.height - outerRingWidth*2 - innerRingSpacing)/2) - innerRingWidth/2

        // If the style is different, mae the radius equal to the outerRadius
        if viewStyle >= 2 {
            radiusIn = (max(bounds.width, bounds.height)/2) - (outerRingWidth/2)
        }


        // Start drawing
        let innerPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
                                     radius: radiusIn,
                                     startAngle: startAngle.toRads,
                                     endAngle: innerEndAngle,
                                     clockwise: true)
        innerPath.lineWidth = innerRingWidth
        innerPath.lineCapStyle = innerCapStyle
        innerRingColor.setStroke()
        innerPath.stroke()
```

Do you know how to apply the gradient?

Answer (score 0):

Paths are normally drawn using a single color.

If you want to draw a path using a gradient you  could create a CAShapeLayer and install your path into it, then make that path a mask on a gradient layer.

You could no doubt also do this using Core Graphics and blending modes.